# Remove all words after starting from a specific word

Tags: sed

How do I remove all the words starting from COMMENT word in the following string?

```
echo "first_mail_sent_date_time datetime NOT NULL  COMMENT 'The date and time',"  |  sed 's/ COMMENT \w*/ /g'
```

The above sed command will remove only the word COMMENT. I need to remove everything after COMMENT but keep the last comma.

I can use awk but I am looking for sed solution for consistency sake.

```
awk -F'COMMENT' '{print $1 ","}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sed command:

```
sed "s/ COMMENT.*'[^']*'/ /"
```

**TEST:**

```
str="first_mail_sent_date_time datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'The date and time'FOO,"
echo $str | sed "s/ COMMENT.*'[^']*'/ /"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
first_mail_sent_date_time datetime NOT NULL FOO,
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/ COMMENT.*,/,/' file
```